# Setting max-height relative to browser window size, not body size

Tags: css

I have a modal popup box on my site, inside the `<body>` tag.

This is the styling of the popup:

```
.modalbox {
    text-shadow: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 22px;
    left: 50%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 90;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Setting the width is simple. However, the vertical content is dynamic and therein my problem lies - I don't want the box to be taller than the browser window.

I've tried setting `max-width: 90%;`, and this works if the `body` of the page is not longer vertically than the browser window.

However, when the `body` overflows (and scrollbars appear), then the `90%` maximum height above is relative to the height of the `body`, not the window. This means that the modal box can overrun out of the window vertically, forcing the user to scroll the page to see its full content.

What I want to accomplish is for that max height to be 90% of the *browser window* so that the entire modal box is visible at all times.

I will handle overflow, I just need help figuring out how to restrict the vertical size in the way described above.

Comment: height? width? Either way, you might be able to do something with [`vw` and `vh` units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), it's hard to tell without a fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this with html or css as far as I know, you'd have to accomplish this using JQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/height/

```
// Returns height of browser viewport

$( window ).height();
```

and then just use whatever 90% of the height value is.

Answer (score 94):

Use the [viewport-percentage lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.

```
.modalbox {
    max-height: 90vh; }
```

Comment: you can use `90vw` for the height to be relative to width rather than height